# Javascript on mobile, can you detect when the display switches on?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

As the title says.

Someone is looking at a web page on his mobile, he switches the display off, he then switches it back on, are there any common or proprietary javascript events that fire when he switches it back on?

thanks

Comment: Since Android 4.4 (with -webkit-prefix): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Comment: Thanks very much, that might make it easier to find the iPhone equivalent as well (assuming there is one)

Comment: Works on iOS as well. But I assumed your question was explicitly about Android.

Comment: I can't try on iPhone until monday but tested and it works fine on Android. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct